# Access DB - Combine and remove duplicates

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access

I have two access databases, *(ProdDB.mdb) and (AllProdOrders.mdb).*

*In ProdDB.mdb, I have two tables that have the same structure: **Data** and **Archive***

*In AllProdOrders.mdb, I have one table: **Outputs***

This is what I want to do:

[image]

What I want to do is create an SQL query that will combine the two tables, Data and Archive into one table and remove any duplicates by checking against three columns: **Prod Ord**, **SO nr** and **Item No**. If these three values are the same for any entry, that is a duplicate and thus shouldn't be included.

After this, I want to left join the AllProdOrders.mdb table: **Outputs** and add a column to the end of my table. This is done by checking the Order Status in that table against the SO nr.

I have already done the left join portion and my query works properly, all I really need to add is combining the two tables and filtering out any duplicates:

This is my code so far...

```
string sql = "SELECT [Data].[SO nr], [Data].[Value (GBP)], [Data].[Ship Date (Cust)], [Data].[Line] " +
 @"FROM [Archive]" +
"UNION " +
@"SELECT [Data].[SO nr], [Data].[Value(GBP)], [Data].[Ship Date(Cust)], [Data].[Line], status.[Order Status] " +
@"FROM [Data] LEFT JOIN [;database=I:\Departments\Production\AllProdOrders.mdb].[Outputs] AS status " +
"ON [Data].[Prod Ord] = status.[No] "
```

I'm going to use this combination of tables in my query with an OleDBDataReader to get the total (Value (GBP) of certain orders.

I'm getting a number of columns doesn't match error but I'm not sure how to rectify this as the extra column is the Order Status column that is added to the end of the query and comes from the second database.

Comment: use a GroupBy() the key then use Select(x => x.First()) to get only one item from the group to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you have an extra column in the second part of the union query. The columns must always match in a union-query. If you add ", NULL as [Order Status]" in the end of the first line I believe the error goes away.